# What is a good way to unit test assembly code?

Tags: unit-testing, assembly

Automated unit testing is considered a staple of modern software development.  Unit testing is hard to do in assembly, because we often don't have the scaffolding needed.  Depending on our asm environment, we may or may not have the ability to:

- Call library functions
- Write to stdout or stderr
- Associate messages with test cases

Even incrementing counters for passed and failed tests isn't simple in asm, as we must avoid clobbering registers.

Consequently, when I test asm, I usually use a debugger and inspect it manually (*shudder*).  I may do something like:

```
cmp rbx, expected_test1
jne .failed_test1
...
.failed_test1:
    int3
    db `FAIL: Failed test1\0`
```

If `test1` fails, the debugger will stop, and I'll see the bytes "FAIL: Failed test1" in the display.  A hack, but easier and less invasive than the other methods I can think of.

A better approach would be:

- Automated: Run and get a count of pass and failed tests
- Diagnostic: Print messages for failed tests
- Non-invasive: Don't clobber regs or mem.
- Minimal assumptions: Don't assume a platform.  Often my asm doesn't even load glibc.

Given the above: **What's an effective way to unit test asm?**

Comment: A common way for environments with minimal to non-existent library support is to leave a status code in a designated register, which a simulator/emulator can pick up. If you want no register/memory, maybe toggle I/O ports instead? The built-in self test performed by microcode inside the AMD Athlon processor (written using an in-house assembler), in which I had a hand, returned 0 in `EAX` if BIST passed, or else the number of the test section that had failed.

Comment: For my 86-DOS debugger I added [some tests](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/ldebug/file/c2d96de77120/test/test.py) that are probably closer to acceptance tests than unit tests: While throwing dozens of tests at it, they're not testing units of anything but instead the behaviour of the entire application. I run the application in a VM (dosemu2 or qemu), either bootloaded or under a DOS, and have it communicate using its serial I/O feature. On the host side it is fairly easy to write to and read from the pty connected to the emulated serial port.